# Rewrite .htaccess not working (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site, and I also have a small sub-website for the contests. I'm trying to build a redirect in html so that:

http://www.example.com/concours-233.html

would go to

http://www.example.com/tirages/concours.php?concours_id=233

This is the code that I have put in the root .htaccess file, under #END Wordpress

```
    IfModule mod_rewrite.c
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^concours-([0-9]+)/?$  tirages/concours.php?concours_id=$1 [L]
    IfModule
```

(The two "If" are in brackets, I just was'nt able to write them in this post.

Can you help me figuring out what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to place custom rewriting _above_ the WP rewriting - otherwise it will have rewritten your request already before it even gets to your rules.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I have move the code at the top of the .htaccess file but it still not work...

Comment: Your pattern demands an (optional) slash after the digits, and nothing more after that. That does not match the URL you said you were requesting.

Comment: Bingo!!!! :) Thanks so much! I have changed the line for: RewriteRule ^concours-([0-9]+)\.html$  tirages/rss.php?concours_id=$1 [L] and it works now :)